# Android where to store images

Tags: android, android-image

I'm developing a new app where I have a doubt about images and folders storage.

I have a DB where I want storae the path of the images and not the images (I don't want to use BLOB because I don't want a large DB). Ok, the question: which is a better place where I can put to the images Raw? Drawable? Assets? and also what type (png or jpg or bmp)?

Thank you so much for any suggestion.

Comment: Raw, Drawable, and Assets are bundled in your app's private data. There isn't really a point to have a database of those. If you're saving images to the external storage, then none of the above - you just have `File` objects

Comment: The default camera app saves images to getExternalStorageDirectory directory.DCIM subfolder Camera. You could create your own subfolder in the DCIM directory. And indeed no need to use a database as you can just list the files in your folder. Well if your app is a camara app. Otherwise just use a folder on external memory. So its unclear for me if you talk about an image producing app or an app that comes with some images.

Comment: The images are preloaded in the app and I don't want the user have access to images out of my app. My problem is to find a better way to add image in my APK.

Comment: You wrote a very unlear post then. Put them in assets. Dont need a db either.